# не работает кнопка "купить жидкость", pytelebotapi

Tags: python, telebot

бот не хочет отвечать на "купить жидкость", на "задать вопрос" все работает, при том что код идентичный

```
import telebot
# import sqlite3
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot('тут был токен')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('купить жидкость')
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Задать вопрос')
    markup.add(btn1,btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'приветствую, этот бот по продаже жидкостей на любой вкус',reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler()
def on_click(message):

    if message.text.lower == 'купить жидкость':

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'вот наша поддержка ')

    elif message.text =='Задать вопрос':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("поддержка", url='https://vk.com/black_dmitriy.bariga')
        markup.add(btn1)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'вот наша поддержка ',reply_markup=markup)





bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: На будущее: токен не стоит светить. Рекомендую удалить этот вопрос и залить его по новой, не указывая токен бота

Comment: Не идентичный же код, для "купить жидкость" вы еще lower пытаетесь использовать. Ошибка в том, что lower - это метод строки, вызывать нужно со скобками: `if message.text.lower() == 'купить жидкость':`. Сейчас у вас не две строки сравниваются, а метод как объект сравнивается со строкой.

Comment: @rusgeli , я перед публикацией его сменил, так что все ок